# Spring Boot tools suite start error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I was using intellij for spring boot but I decided to use suite tools for spring's suggestion.

I downloaded and run it in Ubuntu.

Started a hello world project but there are lots of errors.

```
Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/Servers/Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1-config/catalina.properties'.
```

I did not change anything but this is error.

AS error says, when i go to that page, it shows:

```
base.shutdown.port=-1
base.jmx.port=6969
bio.http.port=8080
bio.https.port=8443
```

when i changed to

```
base.shutdown.port=-1
base.jmx.port=6969
bio.http.port=8081
bio.https.port=8444
```

When i try to close, the errors

```
eclipse.buildId=3.7.3.201602250940-RELEASE-e45
java.version=1.8.0_77
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide

org.eclipse.core.resources
Error
Wed Apr 13 12:21:29 EEST 2016
Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/Servers/Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1-config/catalina.properties'.
```

I cannot even close the project

```
eclipse.buildId=3.7.3.201602250940-RELEASE-e45
java.version=1.8.0_77
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide

org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core
Error
Wed Apr 13 12:21:29 EEST 2016
Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.

org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/Servers/Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1-config/catalina.properties'.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.read(FileSystemResourceManager.java:830)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getContents(File.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.Tomcat60Configuration.load(Tomcat60Configuration.java:355)
    at com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.internal.core.TcServerConfiguration.load(TcServerConfiguration.java:236)
    at com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.internal.core.TcServer.getTomcatConfiguration(TcServer.java:228)
    at com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.internal.core.TcServer.getTomcatConfiguration(TcServer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.getTomcatConfiguration(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:80)
    at com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.internal.core.TcServerBehaviour.getTomcatConfiguration(TcServerBehaviour.java:188)
    at com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.internal.core.TcServerBehaviour.getTomcatConfiguration(TcServerBehaviour.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.setupLaunch(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:496)
    at com.vmware.vfabric.ide.eclipse.tcserver.internal.core.TcServerBehaviour.setupLaunch(TcServerBehaviour.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(TomcatLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

I exited the app and reopened and ran but still same

```
Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.
```

Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/Servers/Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1-config/catalina.properties'.

Comment: This happens with a vanilla STS distribution 3.7.3 on Linux? Does the default created server show up in the servers view? Any steps how to reproduce this?

Comment: yes on ubuntu. when i click servers, i see this Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1-config. in it thosecatalina.policy
catalina.properties
context.xml
jmxremote.access
jmxremote.password
server.xml
tomcat-users.xml
web.xml

Comment: Have you modified any of the files under /Servers/Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1-config yourself? If yes, you shouldn't be doing this. Instead you should open Servers view (not folder in the workspace), find your instance, double-click it and change parameters in the form editor

Comment: No, i just wanted to run helloworld program and did not change anything. But after first run, it said the port is in use so i changed ports. Because 8080 was in use. – I just created a new starter project, only selected web and in messages a lot of errors including eclipse.buildId=3.7.3.201602250940-RELEASE-e45
java.version=1.8.0_77
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide

Comment: Did you select JAR or WAR packaging for you helloworld projects? Can you describe exactly how you launch the helloworld apps?

Comment: You could try enabling the option to auto-refresh resources in the workspace. Not sure why resources in your case got 'out of synch' but the refresh might help resolve it. Go to "Window >> Preferences >> General >> Workspace". There enable "Refresh on access" and "Refresh using native hooks or polling". Also when you see a port is in use, rather than try to change the port you might want to figure out what process is using it and terminate it (probably server process already running!). Terminal command "lsof -i" is very useful here.

Comment: please look at here. i couldnot write here, it doesnot allow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698058/spring-suite-tools-start-error-spring-boot