# Spring suite tools start error - spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I downloaded from here
https://spring.io/tools/sts

I use ubuntu 14.04

It downloaded 427 mb. Then i extracted. executed sts and chose a workspace, use this always selected and ran.

The dashboard and other tabs page came, there were no errors. So then i created a new started. selected only web.

Then clicked run, selected spring boot and the errors

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m      [2m (v1.3.3.RELEASE)[0;39m

[2m2016-04-18 18:07:12.434[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.example.DemoApplication             [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting DemoApplication on caneraydin-270E5J with PID 32440 (/home/caneraydin/Documents/demo/target/classes started by caneraydin in /home/caneraydin/Documents/demo)
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:12.438[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.example.DemoApplication             [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:12.618[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4ba2ca36: startup date [Mon Apr 18 18:07:12 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:15.907[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:19.021[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:19.088[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service Tomcat
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:19.089[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:19.395[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:19.396[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.context.ContextLoader           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6782 ms
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:20.038[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:20.046[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:20.047[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:20.047[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:20.048[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:20.609[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4ba2ca36: startup date [Mon Apr 18 18:07:12 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:20.730[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:20.732[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:20.772[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:20.772[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:20.856[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:21.073[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:21.233[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]

[2m2016-04-18 18:07:21.249[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 14 common frames omitted

[2m2016-04-18 18:07:21.280[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service Tomcat
[2m2016-04-18 18:07:21.381[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application startup failed

org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

[2m2016-04-18 18:07:21.384[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m32440[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/home/caneraydin/Documents/demo/target/classes/, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.5/logback-core-1.1.5.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.32.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.5/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.5/jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.5/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/caneraydin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar]
```

now only those errors. Not errors like here

[Spring Boot tools suite start error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594098/spring-boot-tools-suite-start-error?noredirect=1#comment60983492_36594098)

when i go to commnand line to see which thing is using 8080

```
caneraydin@caneraydin-270E5J:~$ sudo netstat -peant | grep ":8080 "
[sudo] password for caneraydin: 
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1001       14068       1110/java       
caneraydin@caneraydin-270E5J:~$
```

it shows this. Java is using i guess.

I can change to 8081 from catalina.properties

here

```
org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.jarsToSkip =
base.shutdown.port=-1
base.jmx.port=6969
bio.http.port=8080
bio.https.port=8443
```

but when i did,  i got the errors before in the other stackoverflow question.

I want to use another port if it is possble. because 8080 is always in use.WHen i was using intellij idea, it was same.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the spring boot application port by application.properties file as:

server.port=9130

NOTE: application.properties fill will be in you classpath i.e resource folder. Spring boot automatically read this.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html